# Android Kotlin - Volley Multipart request VolleyFileUploadRequest JSONObject response

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

This is the class I'm using: https://gist.github.com/ycui1/5d25672430e6c014a9ef6b422f82652e

this is the code:

```
val request = object: VolleyFileUploadRequest(Method.POST, url, Response.Listener {
        val response = JSONObject(it)
        // finishSend(response, comment)
},
    Response.ErrorListener {
        commentNotSent()
    }
) {
    override fun getByteData(): MutableMap<String, FileDataPart> {
        val params = HashMap<String, FileDataPart>()
        params["file"] = FileDataPart("file$rnds", getBytes(finalInputSteam!!)!!,"fffff")
        return params
    }

    override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        return parameters
    }
}
```

the `it` in val `response = JSONObject(it)` is type `NetworkResponse`

What should the code look like to get the `JSONObject` from response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
val response = JSONObject(String(it.data))
```